# Latest time do say baruch shem kevod after make bracha levatala

Tags: bracha-levatala

After make a bracha levatala, there is a latest time to recite baruch shem kevod? If yes, what is this time?

Comment: Presumably תוך כדי שאילת שלום תלמיד לרב which is either שלום עליך רבי or שלום עליך רבי ומורי

Comment: Is it ever forbidden to say that?

Comment: @DoubleAA https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Safek_Brachot_LeHaKel#cite_note-14. Zeca, the linked footnote contains sources and explanation - would you be so kind as to work some of that into the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps not, but if you're saying it to rectify the bracha levatala, presumably you'd want to say it within the requisite time, assuming there is a timeframe.

Comment: @Nahum this seems correct - it is supposed to be connected to the beracha levatala to be effective, given that the reason is to convert the mention of Hashem's name into a praise. I haven't found any proof of that though, although my Rosh Yeshiva did once imply that there is a "too late" for this takana.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1882&pgnum=62